# Running python script in Blender

Tags: python, blender

I installed Blender 2.6 and I'm trying to run a script called drawcar.py (Which uses PyOpenGL)

I looked around the documentation for importing a script and could only access Blender's python console.

How do I run drawcar.py from the Linux terminal with Blender?

Comment: _For sake of completeness_ (since this SO page is high on Googles results) -- there is a comprehensive and canonical introduction page in the official documentation. Just as usual, it is somewhat hidden :-D [Python API Overview¶](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/info_overview.html) This page describes how Python is integrated and lists all the ways to start python scripts or integrate as extension.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

1. Open a Text Editor view in Blender.
2. Press Alt + O, or go to Text>Open Text Block and open the .py file
3. Then simply press Run script :D

P.s. Instead of opening a file in step 2, you can also hit the "+ New" button and create a new script instead.

Note : In newer versions the *Run Script* button label has been replaced with a *Play* icon : [image]

Comment: Thanks, I just figured this out but I don't see a way to see the output of running the script. I checked Blender's console--nothing!

Comment: It's not in the console of blender, unfortunately. 
It's in the terminal window of Blender. 

For linux/osx, you'll have to run blender from the terminal. 
And I think for windows there previously was a commandline window opened up alongside of blender. You can still turn this on in the help menu, as stated by this article: http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_59_2/info_tips_and_tricks.html It could also be in the File menu though.

Comment: Hi, I have press the run script button but unfortunately it gives me error "Python script fails. look in the console for now" And in console there is nothing. So how can i guess what error with script? Tried to run this with python console using this
filename = "/Users/sandeepsingh/Desktop/objc.py"
exec(compile(open(filename).read(), filename, 'exec'))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<blender_console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/sandeepsingh/Desktop/objc.py", line 9, in <module>
    import Blender
ImportError: No module named 'Blender'
but here shows me error too ?

Comment: Any help will be appreciated..Blender version is 2.65a.

Comment: In windows you can show the Blender system console by going to the menu Window -> Toggle System Console

Comment: even though the original question is not asking for it, I would edit the answer to add in step 2 : "or click on "+" to create a new text and paste your text", since this stackexchange page comes first in a google search for "run python script in blender".

Comment: I've added a P.s. Adding it to step 2 would make the sentence too long ;)

Answer (score 39):

You can also execute the following code in the python console to execute an external script without opening it up in the text editor:

```
filename = "/full/path/to/myscript.py"
exec(compile(open(filename).read(), filename, 'exec'))
```

The above code comes from the following link:

[Blender - Tips and Tricks](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_59_2/info_tips_and_tricks.html)

Comment: Waaay easier than the accepted answer and doesn't require constant re-load when making changes

Comment: But whenever I try to run the script, it reruns the entire script and doesn't delete the last one and mixing both scripts.

Answer (score 17):

this answer is too late, but to help anyone with the same problem

via the terminal:

```sh
blender yourblendfilenameorpath --python drawcar.py
```

from the man pages

```
       -P or --python <filename>
              Run the given Python script file.
```

Comment: Is it possible to pass arguments to the python script?

Answer (score 16):

To run a script by another script or from console:

```
import bpy

script = bpy.data.texts["script_name.py"]
exec(script.as_string())
```

Answer (score 0):

It is likely that drawcar.py is trying to perform pyOpenGL commands inside Blender, and that won't work without modification. I suspect you are getting some import errors too (if you look at the command console). Blender has it's own internal python wrapper for opengl called `bgl`,  which does include a lot of the opengl standards, but all prefixed by bgl.

If you have a link to drawcar.py I can have a look at it and tell you what's going on.